# Unable to Find Remote Repository - Maven via JFrog

Tags: java, maven, jar, circleci, jfrog-cli

I'm generating a custom JAR to publish to our companies internal JFrog artifact repo.  Able to generate the JAR file locally just fine using `mvn clean install`.  Not working from CircleCI for some reason.

Error I'm seeing in CircleCI:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.aether.impl.RemoteRepositoryFilterManager.getRemoteRepositoryFilter(org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession)" because "this.remoteRepositoryFilterManager" is null
```

`config.yml`:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  create-build-package:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:17.0.10
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install JFrog CLI
          command: curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh
      - run:
          name: Configure JFrog Creds
          command: |
            ./jfrog config add myCompany \
              --artifactory-url $ARTIFACTORY_URL \
              --user $ARTIFACTORY_USER \
              --apikey $ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY \
              --interactive=false
      - run:
          name: Create Maven Build Config
          command: ./jfrog rt mvnc
      - run:
          name: Install Maven
          command: |
            ./jfrog rt mvn clean install
      - run:
          name: Upload Package to JFrog
          command: |
            ./jfrog rt u "multi*/*.jar" release \
              --build-name=karate \
              --build-number=$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM \
              --flat=false

            ./jfrog rt bce karate $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM  # collects all environment variables on the agent
            ./jfrog rt bp karate $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM  # attaches ^^ to the build in artifactory

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - create-build-package:
          context: artifactory
```

POM does not have any references to JFrog artifact repo, so not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error is due to running the old version of JFrog CLI.  It has been fixed in v2:
https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/1863